# Telit UL865 3G modem Hangs (Needs resetting) after AT#HTTPRCV=0

Tags: modem, 3g

I'm using a Telit UL865-NAD to connect to a webpage to get data from a php file.
The main problem is that the HTTPRCV command hangs.

See code below:

```
OK
  AT#CIMI

  #CIMI: 730011235559846
  
  OK
  AT+CCID

  +CCID: 89560100000992123469
  
  OK
  AT+CGMI

  Telit
  
  OK
  AT+CGMM

  UL865-NAD
  
  OK
  AT+CGMR

  12.00.716
  OK
  AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","imovil.entelpcs.cl"
  AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","imovil.entelpcs.cl"

  OK
  AT#SGACT=1,1
  
  #SGACT: 10.166.148.143
  
  OK
  AT#HTTPCFG=0,"www.xxxx-xxxxxx.com",80,0,,,0,120,1
  AT#HTTPCFG=0,"www.xxxx-xxxxxx.com",80,0,,,0,120,1

  OK
  AT#HTTPQRY=0,0,"/Inagrap/"
  
  OK
  
  #HTTPRING: 0,200,"text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1",1136
  AT#HTTPRCV=0
```

The AT#HTTPQRY command, refers to the directory where the php file resides.

A second issue,
If I include the php file:

```
AT#HTTPQRY=0,0,"/Inagrap/my.php?D1=val1&D2=val2..."
```

The HTTPRING indicates '0' data

*** Edit Further info

If I test the page through a browser it gives me a response, yet
testing through the modem, HTTPRING indicates '0' data.

The page inserts the data passed in with the GET, to a database.
If I access the page through a browser, data gets inserted into the database.
But run through the modem, nothing happens.

It's strange the modem gives me responses indicating that I connect to the page, it indicates a http status of 200, yet no data is returned and the web code is not executed.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

After the AT#SGACT command, an AT&K0 command is required to turn off flow control.

Two days wracking my brain for this simple omission.